# Any quick way to export data from Filemaker?

Tags: python, database, excel, filemaker, data-extraction

As a user of the database, are there any quicker ways of exporting data from Filemaker using languages like python or java? Perhaps to an Excel.

My job involves exporting selected data constantly from our company's Filemaker database. However, the software is super slow, and the design of our app is bad which makes selecting which data to export a pain. (I have to manually select data one by one by opening the full record of each data. There's no batch export function.)

Please provide me with alternative methods. I feel very stupid in doing this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Exporting data from Filemaker is easy and fast. Apparently the developers of your company's solution made it hard and slow for you. And if you don't have the privileges to modify that solution, then no advice given here will be useful to you.

Comment: The Filemaker solution that I'm using is slow and unhandy. Say if I need to export a list with 2000 records. I have to type in the precise ID of one record, press CMD + N (on Mac) to add a new search, and type in the ID, press CMD + N.... for 2000 times to get exactly what I one! There's no way to bulk search... 
Perhaps there're ways to automate this process? If it's the problem of the Filemaker solution?

Comment: There is a way to automate anything you can describe, but I don't understand exactly what you describe. And you haven't clarified whether you're just a user or do you have admin access and can modify the solution. I suggest you join one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform where your problem can be discussed much more conveniently. SO is purely a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

i always assume there is an easier way to do it.
having not done it myself, i would try this method:
http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/convert-filemaker-pro-4-data-to-excel-export-as-merge-text-file

Convert FileMaker Pro 4 Data to Excel (Export as Merge Text File)
FileMaker Pro version 4 (FMP4) has the ability to export a text file that can be inserted into Excel 2013 or 2016. Note: Other higher versions of FMP can do this as well. These steps focus on FMP4 specifically.

Note: You should have saved the FileMaker Pro file to a known location on your computer. You will need to locate it with Excel.

```
Open the FileMaker file. Find the records you wish to export to Excel.
From the File menu choose Import/Export then Export Records.
From the Save as type box choose Merge (*.MER).
In the File name box, enter a name for the exported file. Be sure to add the .TXT extension rather than .MER.
You can choose to save the file to the desktop or to the same folder as the FileMaker file.
Click Save.
From the left side, double click on the field names you wish to export. Their names will appear on the right side.
Note: Once the names are on the right side, you can re-order them by clicking and holding on the double sided arrows beside their name. Move up or down as needed. This becomes the export order.
Click Export. This wil create the text file to be imported with Excel.
Open a blank or existing Excel 2013 or 2016 spreadsheet.
Click the Data tab on the Ribbon and choose From Text.
Choose the text file you want to import and double click.
This will open the Text Import Wizard. Your data type will be Delimited. Click Next.
For the Delimiter, un-check the Tab box. Then check the Comma box.
The Text qualifier should be a double quote.
Click Finish.
A final window will be displayed asking where you wish to put the data into the sheet. Chose A1.
Click OK.
```

Your data will now be in Excel.

Comment: Can I just mention, what FileMaker Pro is currently in version 16 and your answer is for 4.

Comment: And there was "Export To Excel" functionality built in since version 5, I think

Answer (score 0):

You can also save records as a spreadsheet for use in Microsoft Excel. For more information, see Saving and sending records as an Excel file in the FileMaker Help file. Use export when you want to export records in the current found set or export in a format other than an Excel spreadsheet. Use Save as Excel when you want to create an Excel spreadsheet that contains all the fields you have access to on the current layout.

If your FileMaker Pro source file contains summary fields, you can group by a sorted field in order to export subsummary values, such as subtotals generated by a report with grouped data. This process exports one record for each group. For example, if you have a report that totals sales by region, you can export one summary value for each region.